# R finding difference in snapshot data

Tags: r

I'm a novice programmer in R. I'm in a search of a library or function that can help me in analyzing the following. I've snapshot of all my future orders everyday. Here is the data sample:

```
------------------------------
|createdat|orderdate|qty|total|
-------------------------------
|2014-07-20|2014-07-21|10|1000|
|2014-07-20|2014-07-22|10|1000|
|2014-07-20|2014-07-23|13|1300|
|2014-07-20|2014-07-24|12|1200|
|2014-07-21|2014-07-22|11|1100|
|2014-07-21|2014-07-23|12|1200|
|2014-07-21|2014-07-24|12|1200|
|2014-07-21|2014-07-25|12|1200|
-------------------------------
```

Every day I get one year future orders. I want compute the daily pickup from this. Example for the order date of 2014-07-23 the pickup is -1

Can some one suggest me how to calculate this sort of things in R?

Comment: How do you know what do you get in and what leaves? I understand that it is 12-13 what leads to your -1. What did you tried? Did you grouped by orderdate and then operate? (And if you could improve the format of your data to look like a table it would be easier to understand)

Comment: Yes for a given order date I want to see how much is the pickup from previous date.  This analysis also goes further as 3 days, 7 days etc...

Comment: Does the `createdat` matter at all for this question? Do you just want `diff(qty)`?

Comment: Pickup is diff of same orderdate between two created dates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using @Llopis's nice data and `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
info %>% group_by(orderdate) %>%
    arrange(orderdate, createdat) %>%
    mutate(pickup = c(NA, diff(qty)))


   createdat  orderdate qty total pickup
1 2014-07-20 2014-07-21  10  1000     NA
2 2014-07-20 2014-07-22  10  1000     NA
3 2014-07-21 2014-07-22  11  1100      1
4 2014-07-20 2014-07-23  13  1300     NA
5 2014-07-21 2014-07-23  12  1200     -1

## adding a couple lines to filter

info %>% group_by(orderdate) %>%
    arrange(orderdate, createdat) %>%
    mutate(pickup = c(NA, diff(qty))) %>%
    filter(!is.na(pickup)) %>%
    select(orderdate, pickup)

   orderdate pickup
1 2014-07-22      1
2 2014-07-23     -1
```

#### Quick little intro to piping (`%>%`)

The `%>%` operator is called a "pipe", and is brilliant in its simplicity. All it does is feed that data.frame that comes before it (or is returned by the function before it) into the next function as the first argument. In my examples above, I start with

```
info %>% group_by(order_date)
# which is equivalent to
group_by(info, order_date)
```

In general, the `dplyr` functions always have the data.frame as the first argument, so piping to the first argument always works (you can get around that restriction if you're using other functions). They are also like  `subset` in that you can refer to columns by their names without typing `$` and the like.

For one function, there's no point in piping, but if you're doing multiple functions, it lets you code them in the order you want them done--avoiding the need for nesting or assigning intermediate outcomes.

My first codeblock above could be rewritten as

```
# nesting, very hard to read and understand:
mutate(arrange(group_by(info, orderdate), createdat), pickup = c(NA, diff(qty)))

# one at a time, lots of typing and assigning
info2 <- group_by(info, orderdate)
info2 <- arrange(info2, createdat)
info2 <- mutate(info2, pickup = c(NA, diff(qty)))
```

But I like the `dplyr` way better.

Comment: I am not yet familiarized with dplyr, and I always try to do it with the base functions. But could you explain how the `%>%` works?
To filter just selecting the rows that where `!is.na(info$pickup)` would do

Answer (score 0):

First let introduce part of your data:

```
info= read.table(text="   createdat  orderdate qty total
 2014-07-20 2014-07-21  10  1000
 2014-07-20 2014-07-22  10  1000
 2014-07-20 2014-07-23  13  1300
 2014-07-21 2014-07-23  12  1200
 2014-07-21 2014-07-22  11  1100", header=TRUE)
```

Now we can find which dates are in the table:

```
dates =  unique(info$orderdate)

for (i in 1:length(dates)){
   print(diff(info[orderdate == dates[i], "qty"]))
   print(as.character(dates[i]))}
```

And the output:

```
#integer(0)
#[1] "2014-07-21"
#[1] 1
#[1] "2014-07-22"
#[1] -1
#[1] "2014-07-23"
```

The value is the difference of the date below. 
You could improve this code using an apply function, and improving the output of it to create a table, here there is another example:

```
for (i in 1:length(dates)){
+        diffe=diff(info[orderdate == dates[i], "qty"])
+ date = as.character(dates[i])
+ v=c(diffe, date)
+ print(v)
+ }
#[1] "2014-07-21"
#[1] "1"          "2014-07-22"
#[1] "-1"         "2014-07-23"
```